# Web Scraping Problem using BS4 - Need Historical Weather Info - Text Muted

Tags: python, web, beautifulsoup, scrape, weather

I'm looking to scrape historical weather data from Meteostat.net. You need a key, which I have. When I scrape and prettify the code, the text is muted for the temperature. It pulls up on the site, you can see the temperature text when you inspect the site's html, but when I write the code in Notebook, the html isn't being displayed like it is on the site. Can anyone help me scrape it so the text is not muted? All I need is the top portion of the site with the temperature as the picture I've attached shows. [eb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mDt5.jpg)Would love all the help I can get!! Thanks so much!!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mDt5.jpg)

Comment: Please post the code that you have tried, and what specific issues you are having with that code, so we can try to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is likely going on is the website is loading weather information *after* it is initially loaded, likely through some Javascript framework. The website you linked, Meteostat, seems to have a `json` API that is completely free and well documented [here](https://api.meteostat.net/). Instead of using `BS4`, you could simply use their API to make calls for weather information. Take the following, for example:

```
https://api.meteostat.net/v1/history/hourly?station=03772&start=2019-05-02&end=2019-05-11&time_zone=Europe/London&time_format=Y-m-d%20H:i&key=[YOUR KEY HERE]
```

will return something like so:

```
{
    "time": "2019-05-01 23:00:00",
    "time_local": "2019-05-02 00:00",
    "temperature": 12.2,
    "dewpoint": 7.9,
    "humidity": 75,
    "precipitation": 0.1,
    "precipitation_3": null,
    "precipitation_6": null,
    "snowdepth": null,
    "windspeed": 9.3,
    "peakgust": 16.7,
    "winddirection": 270,
    "pressure": 1016,
    "condition": 4
}
```

You should be able to use the `requests` and `json` modules to gather and load this data.

Comment: Thank you so much!! This helps me A LOT! I'm attempting to make an app somehow and I need historical weather for it. Not sure if I'm headed in the right direction, so we will see, lol! Thank you again!!!!!

Comment: If the above has answered your question please click the checkmark to the left of the response to mark your question as answered. Keeps the forum clean! :)

Comment: Thank you for the head's up! Just checked it! :)